# How to make a double cumulative graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggvis

[image]

How to make this type of graphs in r?

```
Product Revenue Quantity    Rev Cum Quat Cum
Product A   50% 40% 50% 40%
Product B   25% 30% 75% 70%
Product C   15% 20% 90% 90%
Product D   10% 10% 100%    100%
```

Comment: 2 things: 1) this looks like a homework problem you're asking people to do for you. What have you tried so far on your own? 2) you've tagged this `ggplot2`, `plotly`, and `ggvis`...which are you actually using?

Answer (score 5):

`geom_rect` takes 4 coordinates and makes a rectangle. `mutate_at(-1` with `funs(...)` as a second argument creates new variables for each column except for column 1 with the function specified inside `funs`. Same for `mutate_at(vars(matches('cum'))`, but in that case new columns are created for only variables whose name contains `'cum'`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("
Product Revenue Quantity    Rev Cum Quat Cum
Product_A   50% 40% 50% 40%
Product_B   25% 30% 75% 70%
Product_C   15% 20% 90% 90%
Product_D   10% 10% 100%    100%
")[1:3]

df %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, funs(cum = cumsum(parse_number(.)))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('cum')), funs(lag = lag(., default = 0))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Revenue_cum_lag, 
                  ymin = Quantity_cum_lag, 
                  xmax = Revenue_cum, 
                  ymax = Quantity_cum))
```

[image]

Comment: great, but: can you explain your tidyverse manipulations a little bit more?

Comment: @Xenus, if this answers your question you should consider to accept the answer, please. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)